# Terraform filter based on map's minor key on lists of maps

Tags: terraform, maps

I have 2 list of maps. Allow me to show you.
Let's call this one `values_default`:

```
 [{A="abc", B="10"}]
```

and `new_config`:

```
[
  {A="abc", B="9"},
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

Then I need merge or concat them, but in a special way. **What I need to do is Filter out duplicates of `A`, taking the `A` who has the  smallest value of `B`.** That is the final result desired, maybe there is another way to do this from what I am attempting, but as long as I get those two inputs and the expected result, it's fine. For the example above it the result should be:

```
[
  {A="abc", B="9"},
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

Here we took the `A` with the lower `B` value.
I did this so far:

```
locals {
  tmp_cluster_parameters = concat(var.new_config, var.values_default)
  final_cluster_parameters = distinct([for i in local.tmp_cluster_parameters: {
     name = i.A
     value = i.B
  }])
}
```

This means I can filter out ONLY when the maps are exactly the same (`A & B`). I tried many more things, but can not figure out how to get closer to my goal. for the example above, this would not filter out anything. The result would be this:

```
 [
  {A="abc", B="10"},
  {A="abc", B="9"},
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"}
 ]
```

Ideally it should have removed the `{A="abc", B="10"}`

**Edit 1:** answer to question from @macin. here is the actual field as is today and some further explanation

```
variable "cluster_parameters_default" {
  description = ""
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [
        {
            name = "wait_timeout"
            value = "800" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I will have a few default parameters in the future. Those are defaults for MySQL Parameter groups. Here `cluster_parameters_default` is `values_default`, `name` is `A` and `value` is B. The idea is to have some ENFORCEABLE MySQL config defaults that we can overwrite to a greater or smaller value depending on what is allowed. This defaults would create a permissible walled garden for many configs of many DBs. For instance security team might require for us to have `wait_timeout` smaller than 15 minutes. Now you we should also be able to have a different value always that this value is smaller than 15 minutes as required by the security team. Aside there will be many more values that come from `new_config`. I did not want to have to explain all this as this is part of a much bigger project. meaning it will be much more complicated. That is why `values_default`, `A` and `B`. I could change the FORMAT of this variable values_default as it's my own variable, but I can not change `new_config` as this is used by MANY other things outside my control.

**Edit2:** Other Data Sets(DSx).

DS1:
`values_default`:

```
[{A="abc", B="10"}]
```

Then `new_config`:

```
[
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

desired output here should be:

```
[
  {A="abc", B="10"},
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

DS2:

`values_default`:

```
[
{A="abc", B="10"},
{A="cdea", B="111"},
]
```

Then `new_config`:

```
[
  {A="abc", B="8"},
  {A="cdea", B="1000"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

The desired output in this case would be:

```
[
  {A="abc", B="8"},
  {A="cdea", B="111"},
  {A="asd", B="otra cosa"},
]
```

DS3:

`values_default`:

```
[
{A="abc", B="10"},
{A="cdea", B="111"},
]
```

Then `new_config` would be NOT DECLARED in this case.

The desired output in this case would be `values_default`:

```
[
{A="abc", B="10"},
{A="cdea", B="111"},
]
```

Comment: Can you provide better example? `values_default` does not have any duplicates to begin with, so I don't understand what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: added one edit @Marcin. thanks for the question.

Comment: I don't understand - "taking the smallest B"? Smallest of what, how? Can you show an example where  such "smallest" value be chosen?

Comment: We have a repeated key `A` in this case `A="abc"` for that key, if exists repeated in both `values_default ` and `new_config` then we will select one of them. The smaller one based on the value of `B`. in the example above `{A="abc", B="9"}`. I will edit to make this clearer.

Comment: @Marcin added some further details about your question. Again thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand, but just based on your example, you can achieve your outcome using (p.s. `min` applies only to numbers, I don't know how you want to compare strings using `min`):

```
variable "values_default" {
  default = [
{A="abc", B="10"},
{A="cdea", B="111"},
]
}

# FOR CASE 3, but works for other cases as well
variable "new_config" {
    default = []
}


  locals {
  
    # get keys avaiable in our vars
    keys_default =   [for v in var.values_default: v.A]
    keys_new =   [for v in var.new_config: v.A]
    keys_all = distinct(concat(local.keys_default, local.keys_new))
    
    # find common keys that need to be potentailly overwritten
    # using min of B values
    keys_common = setintersection(local.keys_default, local.keys_new)

    # construct overwritten values, if there are any
    # keys must be unique in both vars (no duplicates present)
    overwritten_values = [ for idx, key in local.keys_common:
       {
              A = key
              B = min([for v in var.values_default: v.B if v.A == key][0], 
                      [for v in var.new_config: v.B if v.A == key][0])
       }
    ]
    
    keys_different = setsubtract(local.keys_all, local.keys_common) 

    new_values =  [ for idx, key in local.keys_different:
       {
              A = key
              B = concat([for v in var.values_default: v.B if v.A == key], 
                        [for v in var.new_config: v.B if v.A == key])
       }
    ]
}

output "test" {
 value = concat(local.overwritten_values, local.new_values)
}
```

gives:

```
test = [
  {
    "A" = "abc"
    "B" = [
      "10",
    ]
  },
  {
    "A" = "cdea"
    "B" = [
      "111",
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what i was looking for. it worked with a few tests I did. I am only working with numbers for now.

Comment: @Abel Give me a moment. I see that if `values_default` has two values (not one as in the example), there will be duplicates.

Comment: @Abel A modified a bit with new example. I think now there shouldn't be duplicates.

Comment: I will test and provide feedback.

Comment: It works in many cases I tested except when then `new_config` does not have the repeated `A` meaning it exists in `values_default `, but not in `new_config`. In that case it IGNORES `values_default `.

Comment: @Abel Thanks for letting me know. You can update the question with new example, or create new one specific to it. Sadly, at the moment I can't check it. Tomorrow I can have a second look.

Comment: Did two editions adding other sample data sets.

Comment: @Abel I modified the code to work with the new cases. The example in the answer is for DS3. But this is getting very complex due to your input data (lists instead of maps, usage of strings in B, etc). This will probably lead to more issues in future, thus I would suggest rethinking your design choices, as TF is very poor at doing complex manipulations of input data.